# Simplifying multiple Or Regex query

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to detect that current text contains following keywords "guest post", "guest post", "guest contributor","guest-etc".

i can write query as below.

```
"guest.?post|guest.?write|guest.?contributor|guest.?etc"
```

I am looking for a way to make this regex query shorter.

Comment: I love the idea of `guestpost` matching the regular expressions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the common prefix outside a group, and the alternatives inside the group.

```
guest.?(?:post|write|contributor|etc)
```

Answer (score 2):

If "guest" is constant, then you can move it out of the alternations:

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/oI4hS4/1)

```
guest.?(?:post|write|contributor|etc)
```

Comment: The separator isn't always a space, see `guest-etc`.